# How to show that $m^*(A \cup B) + m^*(A \cap B) \leq m^*(A)+m^*(B)$ for any $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

How to show that $m^*(A \cup B) + m^*(A \cap B) \leq  m^*(A)+m^*(B)$ for any $A,B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

I first thought that I could easily prove it by using the sub-additivity property of the Lebesgue measure. Soon I realized that it was a bit harder than it seemed because for general sets, the best that we have is $m^*(A)-m^*(B) \leq m^*(A-B) $ provided that $B \subseteq A$ and that led me nowhere. So, I have decided to prove it using the definition because the property given in the problem is obviously true for intervals, but I'm still having trouble writing it down because if I want to do it with double-sums I get nonsensical equations:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}l(A_i \cup B_j) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}l(A_i)+ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}l(B_j) - \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} (A_i \cap B_j)$$

which is absurd because the first two sums in the R.H.S are infinite while the L.H.S can be finite.

Comment: I suggest using $m^{\ast}(E) = \inf \{ m(U) : E \subset U, U \text{ open}\}$. I think that's easier.

Comment: @DanielFischer But then I'll have to prove that the given property holds for open sets which is equally hard. Am I right?

Comment: Depends on what you can use. Note I used $m(U)$, not $m^{\ast}(U)$ (the two are equal of course for open $U$), as a hint that we can use that $m$ is a measure, and open sets are $m$-measurable. Well, if we can use that. If not, things are still easier for open sets, since an open set has a canonical decomposition into (countably many) open intervals, and that decomposition gives the exact outer measure of $U$, so you don't need to fuss around with infima.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Since open sets are measurable, for any open sets $U_1$ and $U_2$ we have $m(U_1 \cup U_2) = m(U_1) + m(U_2) - m(U_1 \cup U_2)$ and I can start from there. Now I understand. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Would you please check my answer to see if it's rigorous?

Comment: You nowhere explicitly stated that you pick $O_1, O_2$ such that $A\subset O_1$ and $B \subset O_2$. It's clear that that's the intention (modulo the possibility that you wanted $A\subset O_2$ and $B\subset O_1$), but that needs to be said. Also, it wouldn't hurt to explicitly say somewhere that $A\cup B \subset O_1 \cup O_2$ and $A\cap B \subset O_1 \cap O_2$, but people can gather that themselves.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I added them. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to post an answer to provide a proof of the above-mentioned problem because it may be handy in the future for other people:

Since $m^*(A)=\inf\{m(O): A \subseteq O\}$, for any $\epsilon>0$ we find $A \subseteq O_1$ and $B\subseteq O_2$ such that:

$$ m(O_1) < m^*(A)+ \epsilon/2 $$
$$ m(O_2) < m^*(B)+ \epsilon/2 $$

$$ m(O_1) + m(O_2) < m^*(A) + m^*(B)+ \epsilon $$

Open sets are measurable and for measurable sets we have the equality: $$m(O_1) + m(O_2) = m(O_1 \cap O_2) + m(O_1 \cup O_2)$$
Therefore, we get:

$$ m(O_1 \cap O_2) + m(O_1 \cup O_2) < m^*(A) + m^*(B)+ \epsilon $$
But by definition of the Lebesgue measure, noting that $A\cap B \subseteq O_1 \cap O_2$ and $A\cup B \subseteq O_1 \cup O_2$, we get:

$$m^*(A \cap B) + m^*(A \cup B) \leq m(O_1 \cap O_2) + m(O_1 \cup O_2)$$

Which gives:

$$m^*(A \cap B) + m^*(A \cup B) < m^*(A) + m^*(B)+ \epsilon$$

Since $\epsilon$ was an arbitrary positive number, we finally obtain:

$$m^*(A \cap B) + m^*(A \cup B) \leq m^*(A) + m^*(B)$$

(Thanks to Daniel Fischer for his key idea)